# jquery function for images created dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

I added images to the page dynamically now i need to add some function for this images.
I need to add click event for each image.

this is the code that adds the images (its inside a table that is also created dynamically):

```
for (var i = 0; i < numOfCandidates; i++) {
    var url = "/images/user"+(i+1) + ".png";
    cell23 = $('<td width=cellWidth + "%" align="center" style="height:60%"></td>').html( '<img id="img'+(i+1)+'" src="' + url + '">');
    row23.append(cell23);
}
```

is there a way to add a click event with jquery for the images added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give images a class when you create them and use event delegation .on()

```
$(document).on('click','.myClass',function(){
     //function
});
```

[**Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: is this the right way to add to class:

var l = "img" + (i + 1);
$(l).addClass("images");

Comment: I would probably do it like this instead `.html( '<img class="images" id="img'+(i+1)+'" src="' + url + '">');` @user2958571

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (var i = 0; i < numOfCandidates; i++) {
      var url = "/images/user"+(i+1) + ".png";
      cell23 = $('<td width=cellWidth + "%" align="center" style="height:60%"></td>').html( '<img id="img'+(i+1)+'" src="' + url + '">');
      row23.append(cell23);
      $('#img'+(i+1)).click(function(){})
 }
```